# Is there a way to calculate the confidence interval of the elasticity coefficient in R

Tags: r

I need to calculate the elasticity coefficient, for this I used this very clear and simple article on how to do it through regression analysis.
http://www.salemmarafi.com/code/price-elasticity-with-r/
It does not make sense to retell it, because at the end it is already shown how it is calculated.
The regression equation is taken, then the beta coefficient for Price.Eggs is taken, then it is multiplied by the average price for the month divided by the average number of sales.

```
Sales of Eggs = 137.37 – (16.12)Price.Eggs + 4.15 (Ad.Type) – (8.71)Price.Cookies
(Î”Q/Î”P) is determined by the coefficient -16.12 in our regression formula.
To determine (P/Q) we will use the mean Price (4.43) and mean Sales (30).

Therefore we have PE = -16.12 * 4.43/30 = -2.38
```

I have a question, is there a way to calculate the 95% confidence interval of this elasticity coefficient based on this PE calculation formula?
Well, for example, 95% CI 1.93-3.33.
Thanks for any of your valuable help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** The marginaleffects package will calculate that:

```
library(marginaleffects)

mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp + wt, data = mtcars)
marginaleffects(mod, "mean", slope = "eyex")
##   rowid     type term contrast       dydx std.error statistic      p.value
## 1     1 response   hp    eY/eX -0.2319835 0.0660819 -3.510546 4.471878e-04
## 2     1 response   wt    eY/eX -0.6209837 0.1023271 -6.068613 1.290196e-09
##     conf.low  conf.high predicted predicted_hi predicted_lo      mpg       hp
## 1 -0.3615017 -0.1024654  20.09062     20.08973     20.09062 20.09062 146.6875
## 2 -0.8215412 -0.4204262  20.09062     20.08911     20.09062 20.09062 146.6875
##        wt       eps
## 1 3.21725 0.0283000
## 2 3.21725 0.0003911

# check the elasticity value in the dydx column above
coef(mod)[["hp"]] * mean(mtcars$hp) / mean(fitted(mod))
## [1] -0.2319835
```

**2)** A different estimate (not identical) of the elasticity can be formed by calculating an estimate of the elasticity for each point and then taking the mean of those:

```
marginaleffects(mod, slope = "eyex") |> summary()
##   Term Contrast  Effect Std. Error z value   Pr(>|z|)   2.5 %  97.5 %
## 1   hp    eY/eX -0.2855    0.08533  -3.345 0.00082157 -0.4527 -0.1182
## 2   wt    eY/eX -0.7464    0.14190  -5.260 1.4436e-07 -1.0245 -0.4682
##
## Model type:  lm 
## Prediction type:  response 

# check the elasticity value in the Effect column above
mean(coef(mod)[[2]] * mtcars$hp / fitted(mod))
## [1] -0.2854627
```

**3)** A third approach is to change the model tot he following. It has the feature that the elasticity of `mpg` with respect to `hp` is constant and equals the regression coefficient, i.e. -0.25532, so we can get the confidence interval by simply getting the confidence interval for the regression coefficient using `confint`.

```
mod2 <- lm(log(mpg) ~ log(hp) + log(wt), mtcars)
summary(mod2)
## Call:
## lm(formula = log(mpg) ~ log(hp) + log(wt), data = mtcars)
##
## Residuals:
##       Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
## -0.201432 -0.079563  0.002145  0.078784  0.196150 
##
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept)  4.83469    0.22440  21.545  < 2e-16 ***
## log(hp)     -0.25532    0.05840  -4.372 0.000145 ***
## log(wt)     -0.56228    0.08742  -6.432  4.9e-07 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
##
## Residual standard error: 0.1054 on 29 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.8829,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8748 
## F-statistic: 109.3 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 3.138e-14

confint(mod2)
##                  2.5 %     97.5 %
## (Intercept)  4.3757529  5.2936328
## log(hp)     -0.3747646 -0.1358724
## log(wt)     -0.7410699 -0.3834946
```